# Let $f,g :X \to Y$ be continuous maps and $Y$ Hausdorff. Show that $\{x \in X \mid f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f,g :X \to Y$ be continuous maps and $Y$ Hausdorff. Show that $$\{x \in X \mid f(x)=g(x)\}$$ is closed in $X$.

Consider the complement $\{x \in X \mid f(x)=g(x)\}^c = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \ne g(x)\}$. Let $x \in \{x \in X \mid f(x) \ne g(x)\}$, then $f(x) \ne g(x)$ and since $Y$ is Hausdorff there exists $O_{f(x)}$ and $O_{g(x)}$ open such that $$O_{f(x)} \cap O_{g(x)} = \emptyset.$$

Now $f^{-1}(O_{f(x)})$ is open in $X$ and $g^{-1}(O_{g(x)})$ is open in $X$. The intersection $f^{-1}(O_{f(x)}) \cap g^{-1}(O_{g(x)})$ is non-empty as it contains $x$ and an open subset of $\{x \in X \mid f(x) \ne g(x)\}$ and so $\{x \in X \mid f(x) \ne g(x)\}$ is open and $\{x \in X \mid f(x)=g(x)\}$ closed.

Is it a correct claim that $f^{-1}(O_{f(x)}) \cap g^{-1}(O_{g(x)})$ is a subset of $\{x \in X \mid f(x) \ne g(x)\}$?

Comment: Yes, since $O_{f(x)} \cap O_{g(x)} = \varnothing.$

Comment: Looks kosher to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks all good to me! Here's another approach: define $H:X \to Y \times Y$ as $H(x) = (f(x),g(x))$. It is a standard result in topology that $H$ is continuous if $f$ and $g$ are. Consider the diagonal $\Delta = \{(y,y) \mid y \in Y\} \subset Y \times Y$. It is another easy result in topology (slightly less standard) that $Y$ is Hausdorff if and only if this diagonal is closed in $Y \times Y$, which is equivalent to the complement of the diagonal $\Delta^{C}$ being open. If $\Delta^{C}$ is open, so is $H^{-1}(\Delta^{C})$, which is the complement of the set you are interested in.

The proof above is not as direct as the proof you wrote, but perhaps it will be of value in helping you connect different topological ideas and see things in a slightly different way.